# Bundled node.js application contains "require" statement even though it is type:module

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I am a fairly new user of Webpack, so I don't understand every thing that is currently happening with my webpack configuration.

I have a NodeJS application of type module, which means I cannot use `require` statement to import something. My source code is written in Typescript and if I transpile it using `tsc` every thing works just fine.

However when I bundle my application using Webpack, there are some `require` statements that are added to import some modules, which makes my application not runnable anymore since it conflicts with my `package.json` configuration that indicates that it is a module type.

How can I correct this?

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
import { resolve } from 'path';
import * as webpack_node_externals from 'webpack-node-externals';

export default {
    mode: "production",
    target: 'node',
    externalsPresets: { node: true },
    externals: [webpack_node_externals.default()],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: { configFile: "./tsconfig.json" }
            },
        ],
    },
    entry: {
        "application": './src/infrastructure/application.ts',
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: resolve('dist'),
    },
};
```

And here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../../dist",
        "target": "ESNext",
        
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noEmitOnError": false,
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "module": "ESNext",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "baseUrl": "."
    },
    "include": ["**/*"]
}
```

Comment: Maybe `ts-loader` isn't finding your `tsconfig.json`. Try setting the `configFile` option: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#configfile

Comment: @rsmeral Thanks for your answer. I replaced the TsconfigPathsPlugin plugin with your configuration. I am sure it is loading the tsconfig file I provided but the problem is still here. I'll update the question with your option.

Comment: This is a long on-going fight over the future of the module resolution eco-system. There is no super easy solution, and even the webpack devs did not do that good a job communicating their solution, as you can see from the following long thread. These two comments are probably most relevant: (1) https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11467#issuecomment-691702706 and (2) https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11467#issuecomment-691873586

Comment: Thank you @Domi for your answer. It seems that it's quite instable so I just changed every config file to switch to "type:commonJs". I could still write ES6 modules in my source code which is what I am looking for at the moment.